# Android ImageButton from url

Tags: android, url, imagebutton

Can I set an ImageButton's image from an http URL?

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You need to use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).